# Backbone.js sync event in collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

According to doc here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events collection has sync event fired when I do something to sync collection with server. I try to invoke fetch method on collection and wait for sync event on it, but it never happens. Add event is fired, but I need only one event after syncing all items in collection to update corresponding view. There is another way to get this event fired?

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to fire up sync event maunually in 'success' callback passed as param to fetch method.

```
this.collection.fetch({add: true, success: function(collection, response){
            collection.trigger('sync');
}});
```

Comment: As of backbone 0.9.9 adding sync trigger on success callback is no longer needed. From http://backbonejs.org/#changelog Consolidated "sync" and "error" events within Backbone.sync. They are now triggered regardless of the existence of success or error callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "sync" event is only fired when you change a model. So if you create, update or delete a model, then the "sync" event will fire.

In your case, I think you want to listen for the "reset" event on the collection.

Edit: 
If you're setting the `{add:true}` option, then there is no single Backbone event that will fire after all the models have been added. You have a few options:

1. Just listen to the `add` event and expect it be called repeatedly
2. Emulate a single event by using a handler that has been debounced using the `_.debounce()` function.
3. The return value from `fetch()` is a jQuery XMLHttpRequest object. It implements the [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) interface. So you could listen for that finish. For example:

   ```
   myCollection.fetch({add:true}).done(function(){
       myView.render(); //or whatever
   });
   ```

Comment: Reset event does not suit my needs because I call fetch with add: true parameter.